# How to create MasterEndpoint programmatically

Tags: apache-camel, fabric8

I need to create an MasterEndpoint from a given (as Endpoint instance in Java) FileEndpoint.

Normally i create an class extending the desired endpoint and call all needed setter (e.g. to set context) from with in constructor or in an init method.
Sometimes i create a method that uses `getContext().getEndpoint("name", ClazzOfEndpoint.class)` within the route builder.

But how to do this with MasterEndpoint (preferable without using string literals/constants)?
The problem with extending [MasterEndpoint](https://github.com/fabric8io/fabric8-ipaas/blob/master/camel-master/src/main/java/io/fabric8/camel/master/MasterEndpoint.java) is the unusual constructor it uses. The problem with using `getEndpoint` is: how to connect the returned master endpoint to the FileEndpoint?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot really do this as that master component is not designed for being build programmatically. You get the endpoint via configuring it using a string uri. This is also the recommended way in Camel to setup and define endpoints. Don't program them manually.

Comment: Is there a way to configure the master component with a string using a given endpoint instance?

Comment: Just create it from a string, with "master:someName:xxx" where xxx is the url of your endpoint

Comment: thanks for quick reply: so it would be: "master:someName:" + fileEndpoint.getUrl (not sure about method name)? Since File endpoint is singleton it should be the same file endpoint as used and configured elsewhere, right?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way that suits my needs:

First create the master endpoint together with it's child:

```
masterEndpoint = context.getEndpoint("master:fileLock:file:" + rootFolder, MasterEndpoint.class);
```

To programmatically configure the child endpoint (in my case FileEndpoint) obtain it from master and configure it:

```
fileEndpoint = (FileEndpoint) masterEndpoint.getEndpoint();
fileEndpoint.setAutoCreate(false);
fileEndpoint.setAntInclude(ANT_INCLUDE);
fileEndpoint.setMove(doneFolder);
fileEndpoint.setMoveFailed(errorFolder);
```

It would be extreme cumbersome (and error prone) to configure it with strings.